# Query on variable uri

Tags: php, mysql

Me and our team have an interesting case on selecting data from an database. We were wondering if you lot have a different approach on solving this case.

The case is as follows:

We have an booking system to book 'widgets' on a page. The admin users can book a widget to a page by adding an uri in the backend, like: `/profile/login`.

The query we currently use looks like this:

```
SELECT widget_type FROM cms_pages WHERE page_uri = '/profile/login';
```

This works all pretty good. If there is a result from the query then there is a widget, if there isn't a result  (count = 0) then the admin users haven't booked a widget to that specific page.

Now we have a page which looks like `/profile/login/AEJIJDOJO=`. If there is a widget booked on that uri then the query above does the job. If there isn't a widget booked then we need to get the widget which is booked on `/profile/login` and so on...

We currently have an monkey php solution, so we were wondering if it's possible to fix this with using mysql only??

Comment: Do you really want to keep this logic in your data store? What if you want to change your data store later? I think this logic best resides in your application.

Comment: If you want to fetch widget_type which look something like '/profile/login/....' you can try:

`SELECT widget_type FROM cms_pages WHERE page_uri LIKE '/profile/login%'`

Answer (score 1):

You could use LIKE:

```
SELECT widget_type FROM cms_pages 
WHERE page_uri = '/profile/login' OR page_uri LIKE '/profile/login/%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid trying to find a workaround parsing URLs in MySQL when this is just a classic `many_many` relationship. You need a `widget` table, a `cms_page`, and a `cms_page_has_widget` table.

Then to get all the widgets for a page do something like:

```
SELECT t3.* FROM cms_page t1, cms_page_has_widget t2, widget t3 
WHERE t1.id = t2.page_id
AND t3.id = t2.widget_id
AND t1.id = <page_id>
```

Or using the URL

```
SELECT t3.* FROM cms_page t1, cms_page_has_widget t2, widget t3 
WHERE t1.id = t2.page_id
AND t3.id = t2.widget_id
AND t1.url = <page_url>
```